# IND-CCA secure symmetric encryption

Tags: symmetric, chosen-ciphertext-attack

Although this question maybe looks silly, I have searched similar questions in this forum and googled it but got no desired answers.

IND-CCA security has already been deeply studied in public cryptography. And it is also known that some symmetric constructions (e.g. CBC model) are not IND-CCA secure (for example, see [this chapter](https://cr.yp.to/bib/2005/bellare-chap5.pdf)). However, I didn't find so many results about IND-CCA secure symmetric encryption. The only construction I found is the one provided by Desai in [Crypto2000](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-44598-6_25)

I was wondering, are there any other well-known constructions of IND-CCA secure symmetric encryption (classical secure)?

Besides, could they still be easily converted to a post-quantum version (for example, by double the length of the secret key)?

Comment: Aren't authenticated encryption CCA-secure?

Comment: Many thanks! I just realized that every authenticated encryption achieves CCA security.

Comment: What’s the intuition for every AEAD scheme having CCA? Simply that AEAD == no malleability which limits CCA flexibility?

Answer (score 3):

In [Authenticated Encryption](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Eastubble/dss/ae.pdf), the authors explained the framework and constructions for Authentication Encryption in detail.

In particular, In Theorem 3.2 they stated that "INT-CTXT" security together with "IND-CPA" security implies "IND-CCA" security.

Then, they introduced a general approach to an "Encrypt-then-MAC" construction that achieves both "INT-CTXT" and "IND-CPA" security, which further implies "IND-CCA" security.

Lastly, thanks for the comment given by @DannyNiu.